# One reverse light stays

Tags: diesel, reverse-lights

One reverse light stays on when running on my 2012 Dodge Ram. Where do I start looking to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it on all the time when key is on and all lights off?

Comment: A bad earth on either rear lamp?

Comment: Likely the other bulb is burned out and the switch is bad/out of adjustment.

Comment: Does the other one come on when reverse is selected?  If not, then @blacksmith37 will probably be correct and it is a fault with the reverse switch.

Comment: Grounds.  Loss of a ground has put the reverse light in series with two other lights.